# Target specific elements with font family type

Tags: jquery

I am having to apply jquery to code that is generated by a CMS of sorts. I simply wish to add a class to `span` tags that have a certain `font-family` assigned to them.

The issue I have is performance. This code loops through all `span` tags within the generated code, which could be hundreds. Is there a way of targeting only spans that have the `font-family` of `'Open Sans'`

DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/w5fjqjvL/

`// Works perfectly. Simple each loop iterating through ALL spans`

```
$.each($('span'), function () {
    if ($(this).css('font-family').indexOf("Open Sans") >= 0){
        $(this).addClass('openSans');
    }
});
```

Comment: `I am having to apply jquery to code that is generated by a CMS of sorts` So instead ask question regarding why you need to add code to this specific elements, there is maybe better workaround. And is `font-family` really added using inline style attribute?

Comment: My question has been extensively simplified. Without writing a biography, my question meets my requirements. Yes, inline styling is applied by the CMS. This is common practice when using tools such as CKEditor etc.

Comment: If your CMS is using some specific method to add inline style, then you could override this method instead, that's what i meant regarding XY problem e.g. But imho, your question is missing concrete sample with more context to make it clearer. Now if the best workaround is adding a class client side and performance is an issue for you, then don't use jQuery, use 'plain' relevant js methods instead. And just curious but why do you need to target specific spans regarding their `font-family`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter function to get all element with required condition. and then add class to them all together. unlike adding to elements individually in each condition.

But internally `.filter()` does the same job. iterating over elements and returning filtered element based on condition. the only way it is going to be efficient is at part when it adds the class.

```
$('span').filter(function(){
   return $(this).css('font-family').indexOf("Open Sans") >= 0;
}).addClass('openSans');
```

Comment: This won't be really optimized compare to OP's code

Comment: @A.Wolff: i already pointed that part. will be only efficient for logic of addition of class.

Comment: In this case, would be better to just use function parameter of `addClass()` method to do the filtering part

Comment: @A.Wolff: that is only possible if the css is added via class.  but OP added that via inline css.

Comment: No, i meant using e.g: https://jsfiddle.net/w5fjqjvL/2/  But like said, this isn't really optimized. It sounds like a XY problem to me but i could be wrong. EDIT: or maybe i misunderstood your last comment

Answer (score 0):

Need to use jQuery filter

Check documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
var $addFonts = $('span').filter(function(e) {
    return $(this).css('font-family').indexOf("Open Sans") >= 0);
});

$addFonts.addClass('openSans');
```